# Is this proper C declaration? If so, why does it not work?

Tags: c, variables, declaration

I'm writing a demo program from an educational book made to teach "C" for Unix and Windows. However, sometimes I come across code that, when typed exactly, does not want to work.

Eg.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    /*This next line is the error */

    int num = 2, bool = 0;

    if ( (num==2) && (!bool) )
    {
         printf("The first test is untrue\n");
    }
    else if( (num==2) && (!bool) )
    {
         printf("The second test is true\n");
    }
    else if( (num==2) && (bool==0) )
    {
         printf("The third test is true - but unreached\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, like I mentioned in the title, I am curious if I have these variables declared properly. I am using a windows OS (7).

Comment: What compiler do you compile with ? And which error do you get ?

Comment: What did you mean by "not working"? Does it not present the expected result? Or does this code not even compile?

Comment: It's fine in C, but if you are trying this in a C++ compiler, it may be choking on the reserved word `bool` which is not a keyword in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a C compiler, there shouldn't be an error because `bool` is neither a type nor a reserved word in C.

With a C++ compiler, however, you will probably get a parsing error.

Comment: @Michael: you are supposed to accept an answer by clicking the corresponding tick on the left.

Answer (score 3):

bool is now a reserved word in C++ and can't be used as a name of a variable.  When the book was written, bool was not a reserved word in C and they used it as the name of an int variable.

Comment: Learning from slightly outdated books can get annoying, but I can learn that much more! ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think Stack Overflow's code coloring actually finds the error for you.  Although ANSI C has no `bool` keyword (although C99 does reserve `_Bool` as a keyword), most likely the compiler you're using extends the standard and does define a `bool` keyword, especially since it does exist in C++ and other C derived languages.  The solution is simple:  either force your compier to be ANSI compliant or just change the variable name.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I am using DEV Bloodshed, a general compiler, to build my code. Does anyone know if there is an easily accessable list of words to avoid?

Comment: @Michael And on a somewhat unrelated topic, don't use Dev-c++. It's very old, unsupported and there are much much better alternatives. Code::blocks comes to mind, or the express edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there any that are strictly "C"?

Comment: You should be able to use gcc on Windows 7 and you can tell it to give warnings when violating the standard.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821952/gcc-options-to-enforce-ansi-c-standard-check

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because bool is a type within a C++ compiler, which is a reserved word.  So, it may depend upon what compiler you are using.

Comment: I'm not downvoting this, but it's not reserved in C.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please include the exact error message from the compiler, along with a description of what development environment you're using (Visual Studio, Eclipse, gcc, tcc, lcc-win, etc.). It would also help to know which book you're using; a non-trivial number of books on C programming are **crap**.

My suspicion is that you're somehow compiling the code as C++, not C, and `bool` is a reserved word in C++.  If you're using Visual Studio, make sure the filename extension is `.c`, and not `.cpp`.

Comment: You're right on multiple counts. The book I am using is "C Programming in easy steps". It seems to be a good book, but I bet there would be a better one around. Any suggestions?