# Can a C implementation implicitly include standard headers when including a different header?

Tags: c, header, c99

While reading [Is this proper C declaration? If so, why does it not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694287/is-this-proper-c-declaration-if-so-why-does-it-not-work) I was thinking about

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int bool = 0;
  return bool == 0;
}
```

Is this program strictly conforming? In other words, is `stdio.h` allowed to include `stdbool.h` or is it forbidden to do so? Is this specified by the spec?

Answer (score 5):

C standard headers can not include other headers. This is different from C++, where it is explicitly allowed.

C99 standard, section 7.1.3

> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause[...]
>   No other identifiers are reserved.

Comment: While I believe in you, could you give us some references (e.g., K&R)?

Comment: Hmm, if one header includes another header, then my program effectively includes two headers. Then the identifiers of both headers are reserved, it seems. Or is such inclusion of another header illegal because there is no explicit rule granting this?

Comment: @Johannes - From what I understand, the idea is that a certain header can only include the names specified and generally reserved names (that's the [...]). If you want `bool` defined, you should include <stdbool.h>. Otherwise it is just `_Bool`, and you can use bool like in your example.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's authoritative in any way, but here's what [Plauger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099) says (granted it's for c89).

> The Standard C library provides fifteen standard headers. The headers
>   have several properties
>
> They  are mutually independent. No  standard header requires that
>   another  standard header be first included for it to work properly.
>   **Nor does any  standard header include another standard header**.

I can't find any mention of this in c99 or c89.

**EDIT**

I can see `inttypes.h` includes `stdint.h`

7.8-1

> The header `<inttypes.h>` includes the header `<stdint.h>` and extends it
>   with additional facilities provided by hosted implementations.